# how to get client ip address in static class in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to get ip address of client in `static class` in `asp.net mvc 3`.

But i can't access request object in static class.

can any one help how to get ip address without request object in static class??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the user's IP address in a static class like this:

```
        string ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        {
            ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
        return ip;
```

This technique is better to use that Request.UserHostAddress() as that will sometimes only capture the IP address of a user's proxy.

Comment: It causes "Request is not available in this context error"

Answer (score 1):

you can pass HttpContext.Current by parameter of controller to StaticClass but is a bad practices.

A Best practices is in constructor of Controller get the interface of implement class.

```
 private readonly IService _service;

        public HomeController(IService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }
```

and in Service class

```
 private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;
  public Service (HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            _httpContext= httpContext;
        }
```

then use IOC Containner (Ninject, AutoFac etc) for resolve dependences

exemple in AutoFac (global.asax)

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```